# Teste de uma função do componente

Tags: angular, testes-de-unidade, jasmine

Eu não to entendendo como eu poderia testar essa função do component, eu já tentei algumas formas, mas eu realmente não entendi como fazer

**Função no component:**

```
openModal(){
if(this.RecommendationCount >= this.amount  && this.isEnabled){
  this.ModalIndicationService.setInfos(this.image, this.description,this.id,this.card, this.user,this.title);
  this.ModalIndicationService.postInfos(this.RecommendationCount);
  this.ModalIndicationService.amountInfos(this.amount);
  this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(ModalIndicationComponent,{class:'modal-lg modal-dialog-centered'});
}
```

**Função no spec.ts**

```
    it('open modal test values true', (done) => {
    cardIndicationComponent.RecommendationCount = 10
    cardIndicationComponent.amount = 5
    cardIndicationComponent.isEnabled = true
    modalIndicationService.linkPhoto = 'first parameter';
    modalIndicationService.description = 'second parameter';
    modalIndicationService.idCard = 'third parameter';
    modalIndicationService.CardReward = 1;
    modalIndicationService.user = 2;
    modalIndicationService.title = 'fourth parameter'
   cardIndicationComponent.openModal()
    expect(cardIndicationComponent.openModal()).toBe()
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu entendi depois como fazer, eu vou testando cara parametro, se todos os parametros estiverem corretos, logo o a função funcionara